# Blocking changes to properties/externals when merging in SVN

Tags: svn, properties, svn-externals, svn-merge

I have an environment set up where my externals point to a different location in every branch.  When I merge my code from one branch to another, I always wind up with a merge conflict in the project properties that has to be manually resolved.

This is easily done in the gui since all I need to do is keep my local revision but I need it to either:

1. Ignore the fact that there are discrepencies in the externals, or
2. Automatically accept my local revisions and keep moving with the merge.

I have tried messing around with the --record-only switch, but that seems to block changes to the code as well as the properties.  Is there something that would operate only on the properties, specifically my externals settings?

Comment: If you create a branch, change the externals on the new branch (once or several times) and never change the externals on the origin branch, than there should be no merge conflicts during sync merges. Is the problem that you have to change the externals on the origin branches all the time?

Comment: The process creates several branches and then goes back and populates each one's externals differently after each branch is created, so at the point of the merge after development has occurred, each branch has had a slightly different location of its externals from the beginning.  After reading your comment, I am wondering if I could eliminate the merge by 1.  Creating one branch and running the process to set up its externals.  2.  Copying from that branch to make branch 2 and then running the process to modify the externals.

Comment: And that would be the case.  Thank you for commenting, nosid!